# The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<String>' Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am trying to create an item that will later form the items on a list, one of these qualities of the item are tags, but I cannot seem to get the right return after copyWith for what is an array of items, the code looks like this.

```
 enum Type {
  a,
  b,
  c,
}

class FavoriteItem {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String icon;
  final List<String> tags;
  final Type type;

  FavoriteItem({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.icon,
    this.tags = const [],
    required this.type,
  });

  FavoriteItem copyWith({
    String? id,
    String? title,
    String? icon,
    List? tags,
    Type? type,
  }) {
   return FavoriteItem(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      title: title ?? this.title,
      icon: icon ?? this.icon,
      tags: tags ?? this.tags,
      type: type ?? this.type,
    );
  }
}
```

But I get the error "The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'." could someone tell me how to writhe the tags: tags?? this.tags bit so it will be correct?.

Comment: In your `copyWith` try changing `List? tags,` to `List<String>? tags,`

Comment: Thank you so much! I am of course a noob and couldn't find any examples using lists.